Strict set inclusion of sets given linear and product constraints
I have a set that is characterized by finitely-many linear constraints. I want to determine if adding a product constraint results in a strict subset of the original set.
I can solve these problems by hand with a lot of tedious work, and was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to these types of problems.
To make things concrete, consider the set
\begin{equation*}
\left\{x = (x_1,\dots,x_K) \in [0,1]^K : \sum_{k=1}^K x_k = 1, \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k x_k = \beta\right\},
\end{equation*}
where $K>3$ and $\alpha_1 < \dots < \alpha_K$ are real values and $\beta \in (\alpha_1,\alpha_K)$ so that the set is non-empty.
Let $\{b_{1,j}\}_{j=1,\dots,n} $ and $\{b_{2,j}\}_{j=1,\dots,n}$ be two indexings belonging to $\{1,\dots,K\}^n$ such that there is some value $\kappa \in \{1,\dots,K\}$ that appears strictly more times in $\{b_{2,j}\}_{j=1,\dots,n} $ than in $\{b_{1,j}\}_{j=1,\dots,n} $. Consider the set:
\begin{align*}
    \left\{x = (x_1,\dots,x_K) \in [0,1]^K : \sum_{k=1}^K x_k = 1, \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k x_k = \beta, \prod_{j=1}^n x_{b_{1,j}} = \prod_{j=1}^n x_{b_{2,j}}\right\}.
\end{align*}
I want to determine if the latter set is strictly contained by the former set, or if they are equal.
I can show that the latter set is strictly contained by tediously constructing counterexamples depending on the value of $\beta$ and different cases for the value $\kappa$ that appears more time in the second index set.
Is there a way to think about this problem without getting into the trenches? Without the product constraint, the feasible set is a $K-2$-dimensional subspace characterized by the linear constraints and the unit interval restrictions (this is why I consider $K>3$ in my problem. But I don't know how to think about the product constraint.

It seems that the latter set is strictly contained by the former set but some degenerated cases, but we have to find a formal way to show this.

Yes it is. I was able to show this case by case in a tedious way when K > 4 by constructing counter-examples each time. But I was hoping that there's a theory behind how to approach these problems, since I would like to study them more generally. For instance, if we just had linear constraints, we have nice results from linear algebra to think about these problems.
